# iOS 8 – UIScrollView with children that have dynamic heights

Tags: ios, dynamic, uiscrollview, storyboard, height

I'm having troubles with using a `UIScrollView` that contains multiple child views. One of which has a height that's dynamically calculated based on the length of the text, and pushes the content below down when it becomes taller.

This is a screenshot of the Android version of this app:

[image: Android version]

The description view under the green title is the view that changes height if the description is longer than one line. This means I can't use height constraints on all the views which seems to be what makes the `UIScrollView` work when using autolayout in the Storyboard.

What would be the best way to put a `UIScrollView` inside of a `UIViewController` from the storyboard that contains multiple child views like the screenshot above, **that will work on all screen widths (iPhone 4, iPhone 5, iPhone 6, etc.)** and allow the views to change in height while keeping their position relative to other views?

This is what my storyboard and this specific view controller look like:

[image: Storyboard layout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "iOS way" to do this is using a `UITableViewController` (which in turn is a `UIScrollView` subclass).

You can easily create one using Storyboards and Prototype Cells.

As for the height you can use a reference `UILabel` and return its `textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:` on the table view delegate's `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`, passing `0` as the number of lines.

Also you could take a look to [this library](https://github.com/CyberAgent/AMBTableViewController#features) we use and how it handles [dynamic heights](https://github.com/CyberAgent/AMBTableViewController/blob/master/Demo/TableDemo/PEPhotosDetailViewController.m#L170).

Comment: This is actually what I was doing before, it worked fine before iOS 8, but for whatever reason it stopped working with the larger screen widths. Maybe I'll have to try it again.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do this is to set the number of lines in the label to 0, which will give it flexible height. Then anchor the top and bottom of the label to its neighbors above and below it. The `UIScrollView` has to be able to its content's height by adding the heights of all of its content's children's heights.

Comment: I updated the post with a screenshot of what the view controller looks like in my storyboard and how the tree of views is laid out. The label already has a line number of 0.

Answer (score -2):

You can still use a height constraint, you will just need to calculate the height for that subview first.

To calculate the size of a `UILabel` with text in it, use something like this:

`[textString boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(screenWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX) 
                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin 
                       attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : fontForLabel} 
                          context:nil]`

Comment: Well I size the `UILabel` to fit the text using sizeToFit(). I don't generate the constraints from code, the constraints are all set in the storyboard.

Comment: Then don't use storyboards :) coding is far more flexible IMO. If I were you I'd be using a UITableView with a custom cell for that index. And returning the correct height using the method @AdamPro13 provided above.

Comment: I used a TableView before, it ended up not working out so well now that there's different screen widths with iOS 8. Using constraints in the storyboard is a lot cleaner than using code IMO.